# Making Sheets Hide/Unhide with Checkboxes in a ListBox

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Screenshot1]

Based on the current code as shown below (big shout out to Samuel Everson), I was able to automatically create the checkboxes under a list box (as shown in the screenshot). However, is it all possible for the checkboxes to hide/unhide the tabs? So if i tick ***Warehouse 1***, it should show the tab for `Warehouse 1`, and hide when I uncheck the box; etc etc.

Now the problem is that I don't really know how to proceed from here. Any help would be great! Thanks alot in advance. :)

```
Dim WorksheetArray() As Variant
Dim WorksheetIndex As Long
Dim ArrayElement As Variant
Dim NumberOfSheets As Long

NumberOfSheets = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
ReDim WorksheetArray(1 To NumberOfSheets)

For WorksheetIndex = 1 To UBound(WorksheetArray)
    WorksheetArray(WorksheetIndex) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WorksheetIndex).Name
Next WorksheetIndex

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CheckBoxSheet").WarehouseListBox.Clear
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CheckBoxSheet").ShippingListBox.Clear
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CheckBoxSheet").QualityListBox.Clear
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CheckBoxSheet").SecurityListBox.Clear

For Each ArrayElement In WorksheetArray()
    If ArrayElement Like "Warehouse*" Then

    ElseIf ArrayElement Like "Shipping*" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CheckBoxSheet").ShippingListBox.AddItem ArrayElement

    ElseIf ArrayElement Like "Quality*" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CheckBoxSheet").QualityListBox.AddItem ArrayElement

    ElseIf ArrayElement Like "Security*" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CheckBoxSheet").SecurityListBox.AddItem ArrayElement

    End If

Next ArrayElement

End Sub
```

Comment: show the code that creates the listbox and checkboxes

Comment: Hey HTH! Basically, the codes which are posted as shown above: creates the checkboxes within the listbox. I've created the listboxes beforehand though.. So I just need those checkboxes created be able to hide and unhide the tabs according to the names i've selected. Just in case this might be helpful, this entire set of code is attached to an ActiveX button just so it can run.

Comment: I can't see where's the code that creates the checkboxes

Comment: Here you go! :)     `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CheckBoxSheet").NameOfTheListBox.AddItem ArrayElement`

Comment: That's adding something to a listbox. Are these checkboxes in the listbox?

Comment: @SJR, yes. They are just adding onto the existing list box. I was just wondering if its all possible to do the hidden and unhide function with the checkboxes added to the listbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example which you can perhaps adjust to fit your particular set up.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

Dim i As Long

For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    Worksheets(Me.ListBox1.List(i)).Visible = Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) 'true if selected
Next i

End Sub
```

You might also need to build in a check that one sheet at least is visible.

Answer (score 1):

basically, just repeat for all other 4 listboxes as mentioned in the problem I've posted.

```
Private Sub WarehouseListBox_Change()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To Me.WarehouseListBox.ListCount - 1
        If Me.WarehouseListBox.Selected(i) Then
            Worksheets(Me.WarehouseListBox.List(i)).Visible = True
        Else
            Worksheets(Me.WarehouseListBox.List(i)).Visible = False
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```